# Does Facebook change Api limits or blocking time?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I know about **600 calls per 600 seconds, per token & per IP** and **(>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).** My application considers these limits and sends less than one request per second. It's worked perfectly for a long time, but fb began to return to me "Application request limit reached" since September 25 (2014). I have not updated  the application code.

Earlier in tests I tried to reach fb limit and I was getting fb-block during about 1.5 minute. But now after this test I get fb-block for many hours.

I use fql query without any tokens

I have not found any informations about changes at fb

**Edit:**

I have tried to register new fb-app and use access_token. But unfortunately, I can't use fql with token of new fb-app because fql was deprecated (for old apps fql will work to August 2016)

Comment: I tried this. Unfortunately, I can't use fql with token of new fb-app because fql was deprecated (for old apps fql will work to August 2016)

Comment: And why don't you generate an app access token for your old app then?

Comment: I didn't use app, I sent requests to fql without access token

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by use API links to get stats:

https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=%%URL%%&format=json

instead of fql-queries